# PHP & DOM say where the parsed source code should be in the HTML code?

Tags: php, html, dom

Is it possible with the help of PHP and DOM to say where the parsed source code should be in the HTML code?

With PHP and DOM I output HTML objects from different files, but my problem is that they are simply attached to the end of the file. However, these should at least be included in the body tag.

For example, I take the HTML object with the ID = "header" and want it to be above the HTML object with the ID = "page" and the same for the HTML object with the ID = "footer", only that this HTML object is below the object with the ID = "page".

Example:

```
// target files
$url1 = "header.html";
$url2 = "footer.html";

// create the DOMDocument object, and load HTML from a string
$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$doc1->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url1));

$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url2));

// get the element with id="header"
$header= $doc1->getElementById('header');

// get the element with id="footer"
$footer = $doc2->getElementById('footer');

// header
echo $doc1->saveHTML($header);

// html, body, head with meta tags and more.
include("article.php");

// footer
echo $doc2->saveHTML($footer);
```

Comment: DOMDocument::insertBefore

Comment: If you create a minimal example of your problem it would be easy to show you how it can be done.

Comment: I have added a example. And DOMDocument::insertBefore may can works.